# Cannot add images to existing products in OpenCart

Tags: opencart

I recently upgraded a clients OpenCart system to 1.5.6 and she cannot add images to existing products in the "Images" tab. The image manager comes up and it will display all the images, but when I double click to add it, the box that should have the new image stays blank. The weird part is, when a new product is created the Image Manager works just fine. Or if I use the "add image" button, save the product without actually adding the image, go back in, it works just fine.

I've checked the error logs with no data found on this, cleared the data folder in the cache, I'm pretty sure the permissions are correct, and now I'm stumped.

Comment: This sounds like a javascript issue. Check the console to see if this or any other modification are causing JS errors

Comment: Jay- I've tried a few more things and I'm thinking that it's something other than a js issue. I can add images to new products or save the product with the blank images and go back in, then it works just fine.

Comment: Is it possible this is simply a browser caching issue? I know in chrome, if I replace an image, it won't show in the product panel correctly unless I clear my cache in chrome.

Comment: Vince- This is a cross-browser issue and can be replicated every time. I'm a bit weak when it comes to MySql, but could it be that it's a database issue?

Comment: Additionally, I did try clearing the cache with no avail.

Answer (score 1):

Fixed! The issue was documented in the OpenCart project on GitHub. There were four files in the /admin folder that needed to be updated.

https://github.com/opencart/opencart/issues/829

Thanks for the feedback.

Answer (score 0):

For those who are NOT technically inclined and worry about code changes, the workaround answer given by Kyle I. works just fine and does not need you to change any codes. The workaround is not too bothersome either!

Problem:
Cannot add additional images to existing Product in Opencart. In my case version was 1.5.6

Workaround:
add images to new products but save the product with blank images and then go back in and add your image. This time your image is added!)

What was done?:
Well as explained in the above workaround, it works. If you cannot add additional images to a Product in Opencart, what you do is to:

1) Add a blank additional image to your Product, save the Product.
2) Go back in and add the image where it was previously saved as blank.
3) Now you can see the image added.